# What rules does IE use to determine whether to show the entity body?

Tags: internet-explorer, http

At least on IE 9, occaisionally, the browser will decide to just not show the entity body it was served by the web-browser, and instead shows a custom page of its own. It appears to do this for some errors, such as 403, 404, 500, etc.

Sometimes, however, it *will* show the entity body as sent by the server.

What conditions does it use to determine whether to show the response?

*What I did:* I constructed a minor webserver that takes, via the query string, an argument as to what code to return, and returns (with a status code of `code`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Response {code}</h1>
Hi. I'm an <em>HTML document</em>. I should be the response of a code {code}.
</body></html>
```

I call this via `/my-page?code=400`, `/my-page?code=500`, etc. Sometimes I get the page, sometimes I do not. Chrome verifies the status code is being sent. (And displays the page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently broken by design. The conditions:

- The error is one of [400, 403, 404, 405, 406, 408, 409, 410, 500, 501, 505]
- The entity body's size in bytes is less than the threshold specified by `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\ErrorThresholds`

Also note the defaults:

> The default threshold is 256 bytes for the response codes [403, 405, 410] and 512 bytes for response codes [400, 404, 406, 408, 409, 500, 501, 505]. If the registry entry is missing for one of the status codes, its threshold defaults to 512 bytes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/19/http-error-pages-in-internet-explorer.aspx

Comment: At least one blogging app I know of has a 404 page with a big block of spurious HTML code at the end and a comment explicitly stating that it's there to get around this IE behaviour. Oh well.